# How does the LZMA compression method work?

Tags: algorithm, compression, lzma

I need to know details about LZMA compression algorithm. I know its general concept, but I need some examples explaining it in detail. Can anybody please help me to get more information?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=LZMA+compression+algorithm

Comment: Thanks BenV,
actually I know its general concept, I need more details and some examples about that.
Thanks.

Comment: rewrite the question, state what you know (possibly frow where) and ask the question about details.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lzma

Comment: I believe what Shadi is looking for is something like this:
https://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/curious/compression/lzw.html .

But for LZMA.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).  It "provides the **documentation**, **samples**, header files, libraries, and tools you need to develop applications that use LZMA compression."

Comment: Can you tell us how to use this SDK

Comment: @Frankenstein Download the SDK, look at the documentation and samples, try it out, and then if you have specific questions come back and ask them on StackOverflow.

Comment: In DOC==> 7cC.txt  : there are some  test application called `7zMain.c` but there is no such file in sdk folder ... But also the command 7z.exe or 7z in cmd won't work !!! can you help ... thanks

Comment: You'll have a lot better luck posting a new question rather than commenting on an existing one.

Comment: Ok please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166772/ho-to-setup-and-use-the-lzma-compression-algorithm-sdk

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the examples from here?

1. http://www.asawicki.info/news_1368_lzma_sdk_-_how_to_use.html
2. http://lloyd.github.io/easylzma/

The first link show code that I tried and works. Not sure about the second one but it looks good.

Comment: the first one didn't use incremental compression i think ? can you share with me the code that worked for you chfakht@gmail.com thanks