# Ho to setup and use the LZMA compression algorithm SDK

Tags: sdk, 7zip, compression, lzma

Making some research on the net, I found that one of the most recent, optimized and high-performance algorithms for data compression, especially in term of compression ratio and decompression time is the LZMA Algorithm. It's supported in many popular software like WinRAR, WinZip, and 7-Zip (By default).

I have found the LZMA SDK here http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html
But i haven't found a way to install it in windows or to use the source code provided (examples).

For example : In `DOC ==> 7cC.txt` : there are some test applications called `7zMain.c` but there is no such file in sdk folder ... But also the command `7z.exe` or `7z` in cmd won't work !!!

Note :  i have installed the latest version of 7-zip 15.14

Any suggestions ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LZMA SDK , i found the file `LzmaUtil.sln`that you can run easily in visual studio.

After building the solution you can either add arguments in visual studio or just run it from command line

```
Usage:  lzma <e|d> inputFile outputFile
  e: encode file
  d: decode file
```